# Syntax Error in Bash script

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, error

I'm using the following command to find certain files and delete them.

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(mdfind -literal "kMDItemFSName == '123.test'")
IFS=$'\n'
files=($files)
for f in ${files[*]};do
  if [[ -e $f ]];then
    rm $f
    echo "deleted ${f}"
  else
    echo "file not found: ${f}"
  fi
done
exit 0
```

When I run it I receive this error:

```
Users/admin/Desktop/example.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `do
Users/admin/Desktop/example.sh: line 5: `for f in ${files[*]} ;do
```

Can anyone explain to me what this means and how I might fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Check your _code_ in [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: I don't see anything here that'd cause that error. Check your script for invisible/weird characters by printing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -v /Users/admin/Desktop/example.sh` and see if that shows anything weird. However, `files=($files)` and `for f in ${files[*]}` will both fail completely for anything with spaces in the filename/path; see [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020), but use `mdfind -0 ...` instead of `find ... -print0`.